# How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?

Tags: linux

I'm discovering the possibilities offered by persistent live USB using Ubuntu 19.10 and I was wondering if it would be possible to boot with Ubuntu on Android (i.e. using your computer capabilities through your smartphone) using those multi-plug USB sticks which have both USB3 and micro-USB2.

In other way: can I get some kind of a boot menu on an Android device in order to boot with a persistent live USB in order to access my Linux computer tools and setup from a wider range of devices?

Answer (score 12):

Near duplicate: [Is it possible to boot an Android phone from a USB drive?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40419/218526)

You question has two parts:

## 1. How to boot from USB on Android device?

On most of the recent Android devices you can't boot even Android from USB, rather Ubuntu or some other OS.

### PCs:

PC world has a standardization. BIOS / UEFI, **ACPI** and **discoverable buses** make every PC almost identical to the OS, so we can boot any OS. **BIOS** lets you select boot device, loads **bootsecotor** / MBR and bootloader which loads OS kernel. **UEFI** [Boot Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/uefi-boot-manager-1/) is even more sophisticated, it can read filesystems and load one of multiple BLs or even [Linux kernel directly](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/3c7f255039a2ad6ee1e3890505caf0d029b22e29) from EFI System Partitions (ESP).

[image]

[Multiboot compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiboot_specification) BLs can load multiple OSes. Windows BOOTMGR and Linux **GRUB** can also chain load each other. Latter can act as **1st stage** BL (MBR/VBR) as well as **2nd stage** (GUI boot manager which reads configuration from filesystem). See [Boot Process: Android vs. Linux](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux-t3785254)

### Phones:

Phone's world has a lot of fragmentation. They are based on [**SoC**](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-it-works-systems-on-a-chip-soc-93587/) design, so every vendor implements its own closed-source firmware. **Non-enumeration-capable** buses depend on **Device Tree**, which is stored on flash storage as blob (DTB), and loaded by final BL (like [**U-Boot**](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/v2019.10/doc/README.mediatek#L30), [**LittleKernel**](https://github.com/littlekernel/lk/wiki/Introduction) / [**Aboot**](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/9c4c075b7fc8d79a79b1dcff451a345054b3b263)) and Linux kernel. So SoC firmware has to bootstrap the device to BL stage so that it's able to identify hardware.

[image]
<sup>Image source: [Exploiting Qualcomm EDL Programmers](https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1)</sup>

SoC firmware cannot boot from a generic MBR/VBR or filesystem, instead it has **hard-coded paths** to partitions containing BLs. Also the strict [**Chain of Trust**](https://lineageos.org/engineering/Qualcomm-Firmware/) in boot process loads only signed binaries, unlocked BL can break this chain. See [Rooting Android phone without unlocking BL](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526), [VB](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/verified-boot) and [AVB](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/avb).

However final BL allows somewhat interaction with user to boot **fastboot**, or Linux kernel from **boot** or **recovery** partition. Both partitions don't have filesystems, but a standard raw format as per Android specifications.

---

### Conclusion:

So due to **small size**, non-standardization, **closed-source** / signed nature of firmware and minimal functionality, **SoC firmware + DT + Aboot** setup is no way comparable to **BIOS / UEFI + ACPI + GRUB** setup. Functionalities like USB communication and graphical selection menus would make the BL kernel bigger than the by-design acceptable **size limit**. [Note that](https://github.com/littlekernel/lk/wiki/Introduction) *"on embedded ARM platforms the core of LK is typically 15-20 KB."*

However [SoCs can boot from USB](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/38128), particularly those used with **development boards** or single board PCs. See [Difference between BootRom and BootLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666043/9165920).

[**EFIDroid**](https://github.com/efidroid/projectmanagement/wiki) is a 2nd stage BL based on UEFI ([EDK-II](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/EDK-II)). Currently it replaces kernel in `boot` partition (like other multi-boot hacks), not the original BL.

But we may see (SoC firmware and/or) some (or all) BLs being replaced with UEFI and Device Tree with ACPI (particularly on ARM as it's [not very unlikely](https://www.linaro.org/blog/when-will-uefi-and-acpi-be-ready-on-arm/)). It'll make booting from USB devices on mobile phones more probable. For instance Qualcomm's Sanpdaragon 835 already has its SBL replaced with [**UEFI-based XBL**](https://worthdoingbadly.com/qcomxbl/) (which also supports ACPI on Windows) and Aboot with **ABL**. See [UEFI on ARM-V8  based Linux Embedded System](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/f/embedded-forum/7016/uefi-on-arm-v8-based-linux-embedded-system).

---

## 2. How to boot Ubuntu on Android device?

On Android devices it's not possible to boot Ubuntu even from SD card or internal flash memory, rather USB.

### Hardware Discovery:

Generic OSes like Ubuntu are not modified for a specific hardware environment. On an **ACPI compliant** system, after power on, OS may immediately start querying buses: *"what hardware is attached to you?"*, which is not the case with DT based devices. See [The case of UEFI for Windows on ARM](https://www.imbushuo.net/blog/archives/601).

Similarly on PCs **Power Management** is looked after by ACPI while on phones PMIC is usually a part of SoC - again hardware specific.

### Kernel:

Ubuntu userspace is not compatible with Android kernel as latter is [largely modified](https://elinux.org/images/d/d6/Android_common_kernel_and_out_of_tree_patchset.pdf) e.g. Paranoid Networking, `qtaguid`, USB gadgets etc. It's theoretically possible to boot Ubuntu kernel from `boot.img` e.g. using `fastboot`, or load it by Android kernel using [`kexec`](https://github.com/kexecboot/kexecboot/wiki/how_kexecboot_works). However even bigger problem is vendor's incomplete implementations of **hardware drivers** in kernel, which are not part of upstream kernel source (the one used by Ubuntu). Running **console login** and traditional **X server** etc. might not be easy to achieve, see [Android vs. Linux](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75905973&postcount=2).

### Binary Blobs:

Android is not strictly based on UNIX's *"Everything is a file"* theory. Mainly due to license issues, a lot of hardware work is managed by (again) closed-source vendor specific [**HALs**](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hal) which act as bridge between Android's native/Java framework and kernel e.g. sound, graphics, RIL, fingerprint, camera, sensors and so on. Since Android 8, [HIDL](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture#hidl) (based on [Binder IPC](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#ipc)) specifically separates vendor-specific [binary blobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_device_driver) from AOSP as well as Linux kernel.

### Hardware Abstraction:

In addition to binary blobs, AOSP userspace daemons like `surfaceflinger`, `audioserver` and `gatekeeperd` also interface Java stack (which runs apps) on one end, and kernel or HALs on other (which interface hardware). So every hardware component is not simply a file in `/dev` with [well documented kernel interface](http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto), instead there are layers of Android-specific [**IPCs**](https://source.android.com/security/overview/app-security#interprocess-communication) and APIs between apps and hardware.

This model enables AOSP Java framework to be agnostic about lower-level driver implementations, and restricts apps direct access to hardware resources. Apps need **manifest permissions** to pass through [**protected APIs**](https://source.android.com/security/overview/app-security#the-android-permission-model-accessing-protected-apis) in order to access a system resource including storage, network, camera, mic, sound etc.

### Partitions:

AOSP depends on a few partitions like `/system` and `/data` but HALs need more. On Qualcomm devices vendor daemons like `sensors.qti`, `qseecomd`, `rmt_storage` and `wcnss_service` read and write to raw block devices (e.g. **ssd**, **rpmb**, **fsg**) and filesystems (e.g. **modem**, **persist** and **dsp**). So camera, sensors, TEE, Wi-Fi, bluetooth, fingerprint, aDSP etc. won't work without extra partitions. SoC, processors, modem, TZ, RPM and BLs also use other partitions for boot process, OTAs, recovery, secure boot, encryption, boot/charging logo and so on. Read more about [Android Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565).

So it's not possible to boot an OS entirely from a single partition. PCs can be started if there is no storage device, but Android devices won't turn on [if eMMC / UFS is damaged](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218346/218526). **Hardware-specific partitions** are required at pre-kernel as well as post-kernel stages. That's why Android devices are more [vulnerable to be permanently bricked](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526).

---

### Conclusion:

On Android phones there is no generic Android OS, instead we have **ROMs** which are tightly bound to a specific hardware. So booting Ubuntu on Android device requires integrating all hardware-related vendor code in Ubuntu kernel and/or userspace.

---

**LINKS:**

- [Why don't Android hardware manufacturers build to a common BIOS specification?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/53aaf5/why_dont_android_hardware_manufacturers_build_to/)
- [Device Tree: What It Is?](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_What_It_Is)
- [Engaging Device Trees.pdf](https://elinux.org/images/e/e2/Engaging_Device_Trees_0.pdf)
- [U-Boot on Arm32, AArch64 and beyond](https://www.linaro.org/blog/u-boot-on-arm32-aarch64-and-beyond/)
- [Nvidia Tegra Boot Flow](https://http.download.nvidia.com/tegra-public-appnotes/tegra-boot-flow.html)
- [LK BL Overview.pdf](https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/28821/lm80-p0436-1_little_kernel_boot_loader_overview.pdf)
- [Booting Android (Slides)](https://www.slideshare.net/chrissimmonds/android-bootslides20)
- [Comparison of bootloaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders)
- [Android HAL and Device driver architecture](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/system-on-module-SOM/android-hal-and-device-driver-architecture)