# Can we upgrade oppo a37m to higher color os?

Tags: oppo

https://www.gsmarena.com/oppo_a37-8162.php

I am looking for clone apps feature in settings and I can't find it.

It requires color os 3.1. I have color os 3

Also if I press os update doesn't work/.

Is there any data where the phone os is upgradeable to 3.1 or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226636/how-to-upgrade-my-android-device-to-latest-android-version)

Comment: If there is an update for your device available you can install it via system settings. If no update is shown then there is no update.

Comment: There is an update button. However, pressing it produces nothing

Comment: You can't expect that a 5 year old mid priced phone still receives updates. In 2016 you were luck if you got one major Android version upgrade. Only the expensive high-end devices got more updates.

Comment: There is not much development in custom scene for this device model. only some users played with kernel source code, and some [rumors](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/development-reborn-crowdfunding-for-althafvly-oppo-a37-device.4135947) about unofficial LineageOS 17.1 (android 10)

Comment: So 3.0 is how far it goes for oppo 37 can anyone confirm? Also why can't old devices keep getting updated? What stops it?

Comment: [Why do apps stop supporting older Android versions after some time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234334/why-do-apps-stop-supporting-older-android-versions-after-some-time) // [How to pick a phone for long usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234232/how-to-pick-a-phone-for-long-usage) // [What are possible consequences of not installing updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220188/what-are-possible-consequences-of-not-installing-updates)

Comment: [If I buy the cheapest possible Android smartphone today, how long can I keep it without having to buy a new one?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236538/if-i-buy-the-cheapest-possible-android-smartphone-today-how-long-can-i-keep-it) // [Replacing Android OS on Android phone with Linux OS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233897/replacing-android-os-on-android-phone-with-linux-os) // [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-android-on-my-device)

Comment: some custom ROMs (probably all based android 5 haven't checked any) https://androidfilehost.com/?w=developers&did=4285