# Can we and How to create Live USB for Virtual Android OS with standalone apps from USB?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtualization

Can we run Virtual Android OS with standalone apps from USB dribe from Android mobiles if yes share like how can we don it?

Is it possible in Android to install or create program or run standalone apps (as in Windows apps software's runs without installing) on USB stick or create a live android USB OS with 500-1000 apps if yes how share links.

As Ubuntu Linux notable live USB be created but it will not run Android apps is it possible to run android apps on Ubuntu..Or run  create a. Android virtual os from Android itself

Comment: Android apps always require an installation, running an Android app just from an APK or a bunch of split APKs is not possible.

Comment: You cannot boot from a USB drive on Android devices irrespective of which OS it contains: [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)

Comment: @irfan Latin bro thank yes Ubuntu live USB is good but 
I think Ubuntu is Linux OS can we install Android apps on ubuntu I doubt...I have founded an app named   
MULTI ROM which can run multiple stock from on rooted mobile but I want some virtual USB solution through which I can run  boot Android OS and 100-200-500 apps virtually from USB and unplug when not needed is it possible with to install Android apps on live USB of Ubuntu Linux is.

Comment: No, we can't install apks in Ubuntu,

Comment: And you never need all of those apps. Google Play Store and F-Droid are enough to get apps you need. Most apps on Android are for free or at least mostly cheap if there is really no free alternative.