# Can i install windowsphone 8.1 into samsung a10?

Tags: samsung, windows-mobile

I have a samsung a10 device and in my high school years i had a lumia windows phone whose tiles interface seemed to look really cool unlike anything google have ever imagined for their android os, now how do i download a windowsphone 8.1 or windowsphone 10.1 operating system and install on this phone, i have the admin rights to the device after rooting it, thanks...
Is this even possible with this samsung phone?

Comment: The chances of this being possible are negligible.

Comment: Sorry, Android Enthusiasts is possibly not the right community to ask since they don't have much/any experience with Windows Phone OS. However, there's a similar question on our sister site for Windows Phone experts: [Is there any way to install Windows Phone on an Android device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8722/9802) with the answer: no (in addition to [Windows Phone is already EoL](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16686/9802)).

Comment: If you want to understand technically why it's not possible, check [Is it possible to install Windows, iOS or Linux on Android phone?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-is-it-possible-to-install-windows-ios-or-linux-on-android-device.3763961) and [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526).

Comment: OKay thanks @Irtan Latif

Comment: THanks @Andrew T

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. If you like the tile interface you can simply install an Android launcher app that uses such an UI. In my opinion you should ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com what the preferred launcher app with Windows 10 tiling UI is. That is something realistic instead of trying to resurrect a dead closed-source OS on devices not built for it.

Comment: Windowsphone is still better at the user interface design, i bet even Larry page knows that.