# How use Live boot on Android devices?

Tags: adb, fastboot, boot, linux

I want Live boot a Mobile Linux distribution(for example Mobian) on the Android device. I also have an adb and fastboot and my device is rooted. Is there a way to Live boot on Android?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your device is either OnePlus 6(T) or Pocophone F1?

Comment: "Live boot" is only possible for very small systems like recovery which fits totally into the boot image. The only other way to temporary boot something is [Dynamic System Updates (DSU)](https://developer.android.com/topic/dsu) but that requires the data to be flashed onto the device to a separate partition. It is designed to easily try out beta versions of new OS versions.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220677/44325)

Comment: @alecxs No, My device is a bit old with Android 4, so I think there's a lot of access open. I read where the operating system can be booted from the SD card, and my mobile connects to the OTG cable as well.

Comment: Mobian is available only for OnePlus 6(T) and Pocophone F1 (both projects far from stable) https://wiki.mobian-project.org/doku.php?id=devices

Comment: @alecxs I want to take this risk and try it on my device. Finally, it needs to be tested on different devices to develop it, and there has to be a way to do it.

Comment: It's not about risk it's about availbility. You can't have what doesn't exist